# Do Java methods headSet and tailSet in Java class TreeSet work in log(N) time?

Tags: java, collections

It is written in the JavaDoc that the basic operations on a  TreeSet work in log(N) time, where N is the size of the set. It seems to me that the headSet and tailSet methods should find the beginning of the views they're calculating via something like a binary search if the set is big enough, but the JavaDoc is silent on this.

Comment: Your assumption makes sense, but since it's not specified in the Javadoc, implementations of `headSet` and `tailSet` are not guaranteed to work in log(N) time.

Answer (score 9):

The docs say nothing about `headSet` and `tailSet`'s time complexity. All they say is:

> Returns a **view** of the portion of this set whose elements are strictly less than toElement. The returned set is backed by this set, so changes in the returned set are reflected in this set, and vice-versa. The returned set supports all optional set operations that this set supports.

(I'm emphasizing *view*). And *view* is indeed the most important part. Creating views is always a `O(1)` operation, worst case, as only wrapper classes are created. No key search is performed, just type checks, and in fact no other operations are triggered, either.

Here's `TreeSet.headSet(E toElement)` code:

```
public SortedSet<E> headSet(E toElement) {
    return headSet(toElement, false);
}
```

And here's `TreeSet.headSet(E toElement, boolean inclusive)` code:

```
public NavigableSet<E> headSet(E toElement, boolean inclusive) {
    return new TreeSet<>(m.headMap(toElement, inclusive));
}
```

As you may know, `TreeSet` is backed by a `TreeMap` instance. This is what the `m` property actually is. So the operation above delegates to the `TreeMap.headMap(E toElement, boolean inclusive)` method and then creates a new `TreeSet` instance backed by the `NavigableMap` instance returned by `TreeMap.headMap(E toElement, boolean inclusive)`.

First, let's see the `TreeSet` constructor:

```
TreeSet(NavigableMap<E,Object> m) {
    this.m = m;
}
```

As you see, this is just an assignment.

Then, let's dig into the `TreeMap.headMap(E toElement, boolean inclusive)` method's code:

```
public NavigableMap<K,V> headMap(K toKey, boolean inclusive) {
    return new AscendingSubMap<>(this,
                                 true,  null,  true,
                                 false, toKey, inclusive);
}
```

This just creates and returns an instance of the `AscendingSubMap` static nested class. Here's `AscendingSubMap` constructor's code:

```
AscendingSubMap(TreeMap<K,V> m,
                boolean fromStart, K lo, boolean loInclusive,
                boolean toEnd,     K hi, boolean hiInclusive) {
    super(m, fromStart, lo, loInclusive, toEnd, hi, hiInclusive);
}
```

This just delegates to the superclass' constructor (`AscendingSubMap`'s superclass is `NavigableSubMap` static nested abstract class). Here's `NavigableSubMap` constructor's code:

```
NavigableSubMap(TreeMap<K,V> m,
                boolean fromStart, K lo, boolean loInclusive,
                boolean toEnd,     K hi, boolean hiInclusive) {
    if (!fromStart && !toEnd) {
        if (m.compare(lo, hi) > 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromKey > toKey");
    } else {
        if (!fromStart) // type check
            m.compare(lo, lo);
        if (!toEnd)
            m.compare(hi, hi);
    }

    this.m = m;
    this.fromStart = fromStart;
    this.lo = lo;
    this.loInclusive = loInclusive;
    this.toEnd = toEnd;
    this.hi = hi;
    this.hiInclusive = hiInclusive;
}
```

As you see, this is only checking the arguments for correctness and assigning them to properties.

Here `m` is the enclosing `TreeMap` instance (remember that `NavigableSubMap` is a static nested abstract class). The `TreeMap.compare(Object k1, Object k2)` method is as follows:

```
final int compare(Object k1, Object k2) {
    return comparator==null ? ((Comparable<? super K>)k1).compareTo((K)k2)
        : comparator.compare((K)k1, (K)k2);
}
```

This method just compares its arguments as appropriate and here it's used just to check the bounds of the submap. (Remember that `TreeMap` keys can be either `Comparable` or not. If they aren't, a `Comparator` must be provided when constructing the `TreeMap` instance, and this is what the `comparator` attribute is in the code above).

And this is all that is done when invoking the `headSet` method. `tailSet` follows the same pattern (just the bounds of the final submap are different).

**So, as a conclusion, `headSet` and `tailSet` are actually `O(1)` worst case.**

Note: I've checked the code for both `JDK 8 v1.8.0_181` and `openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25` versions. I'm pretty certain that the in-between versions haven't been changed either.

---

**EDIT:**

Concerning time complexity of accessing the first element of the view returned by `headSet`, i.e. if you were to iterate it, the implementation needs to perform an `O(logN)` operation to reach the leftmost leaf of the `TreeSet` (after all, a `TreeSet` is backed by a `TreeMap`, which in turn is implemented as a red/black tree).

Iterating the set view returned by `tailSet` has the same time complexity: `O(logN)`. This is because the implementation needs to perform a search of the node whose value is closer to the provided lower bound, and this search is also `O(logN)`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this answer.  I guess that I was hoping that constructing a headSet or tailSet view might have somehow involved navigating to the actual beginning of the iterator. I'll ask another question.

Comment: @BlaiseZydeco That happens lazily, when i.e. you iterate the returned set. But if you do i.e. a contains, then there's no need to search for the bound passed to headSet/tailSet.

Comment: @Federico Yes, so I realized as soon as the word "view" was emphasized. The very specific issue I was interested in is how quickly the size of a headSet or tailSet is determined.

Comment: @BlaiseZydeco wait, size? Do you mean the size of the set view as returned by the size() method returned by either headSet, tailSet or subset?

Comment: @Federico The number of elements that would be visited in a complete iteration over the headSet or tailSet view.  I trust that's what the size() method is supposed  to return. e.g, if I say primesLt100.headSet(10).size(), I should get 4 as the answer.

Comment: There's no way to know that in advance. Even using `.size()` on one of the views of the set is `O(n)`, because internally, the implementation doesn't know the size of the subsets (only the size of the complete set), so, in order to compute it, it iterates the whole headset/tailset/subset and counts elements one by one. This is one big limitation of `TreeSet`/`TreeMap`, because they can't be used to calculate the lengths of prefix/suffix sets efficiently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181296/discussion-between-federico-peralta-schaffner-and-blaise-zydeco).